# Is there a notion of $\mathfrak{g}$-$\mathfrak{h}$-bimodules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ be two Lie algebras.

> Is there a notion of $\mathfrak{g}$-$\mathfrak{h}$-bimodules such that $\mathfrak{g}$ becomes a $\mathfrak{g}$-$\mathfrak{g}$-bmodule via the adjoint actions of $\mathfrak{g}$ on itself from the left and from the right?

My thoughts so far:

1. One could try to define a $\mathfrak{g}$-$\mathfrak{h}$-bimodule as a $\operatorname{U}(\mathfrak{g})$-$\operatorname{U}(\mathfrak{h})$-bimodule, or equivalently as a vector space $M$ together with a left action of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $M$ and a right action of $\mathfrak{h}$ on $M$, such that these two actions commute. But this does not apply to the adjoint actions, so it doesn’t make $\mathfrak{g}$ into a $\mathfrak{g}$-$\mathfrak{g}$-bimodule.
2. There seems to exist the notion of a $\mathfrak{g}$-bimodule (coming from the more general notion of bimodules of a Leibniz algebra). For this, $\mathfrak{g}$ acts both from the left and from the right on $M$ (compatible with commutators) such that
   $$
     (x \cdot m) \cdot y
     - x \cdot (m \cdot y)
     = [x, y] \cdot m \,.
   $$
   (Or some variation of this formula.)
   But I don’t see how this definition could be generalized to a definition of $\mathfrak{g}$-$\mathfrak{h}$-bimodules.

Comment: Note that the notion of bimodule that you wrote in paragraph 2. generalizes the notion of a module. In case of the adjoint representation, the formula is just the Jacobi identity. For arbitrary representation $\lambda$, define a right action $\rho := -\lambda$ and then $\lambda([x,y]) = [\lambda (x),\lambda (y)]$ can be rewritten as $$[x,y]\cdot m = \lambda([x,y])m = \lambda(x)\lambda(y)m - \lambda(y)\lambda(x)m = \rho(y)\lambda(x)m-\lambda(x)\rho(y)m =(x\cdot m)\cdot y - x\cdot(m\cdot y).$$

Comment: The left and the right action are not of equal standing in the formula, the right action doesn't appear on the RHS of the formula. One obvious way to generalize this to $\frak g$-$\frak h$ bimodule is to let $\frak h$ act on $\frak g$ on the right and replace $-\operatorname{ad}_y x$ with this right action. I have no idea whether this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

A left representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ is a vector space $V$ together with a linear map $\rho \colon \mathfrak{g} \to V$ such that $\rho([x, y]) = \rho(x) \rho(y) - \rho(y) \rho(x)$ for all $x, y \in \mathfrak{g}$. I would guess that a right representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $V$ is then a linear map $\pi \colon \mathfrak{g} \to V$ such that $\pi([x, y]) = \pi(y) \pi(x) - \pi(x) \pi(y)$.

If $\pi$ is a right representation, then $-\pi$ is a left representation, since $$(- \pi)([x, y]) = (-\pi)(x) (-\pi)(y) - (-\pi)(y) (-\pi)(x).$$
This shows that there is almost no difference between left and right representations of Lie algebras. Furthermore, the actions of two left representations $\rho, \eta \colon \mathfrak{g} \to V$ commute ($\rho(x) \eta(y) = \eta(y) \rho(x)$ for all $x, y \in \mathfrak{g}$) if and only if the actions of $\rho$ and $(-\eta)$ commute and conversely.

Therefore, any $(\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{h})$-bimodule $V$ with actions $(\rho, \pi)$ could just as well be considered a $\mathfrak{g} \times \mathfrak{h}$-module with the actions $(\rho, -\pi)$. So the answer to your question is that there is a notion of bimodules, but it is not more interesting than just considering modules over products of Lie algebras.

Comment: You are correct with the notion of a right representation of a Lie algebra. When you think of groups, a left representation is a group homomorphism, while a right representation is a group antihomomorphism. If you differentiate a Lie group homomorphism, you get a Lie algebra homomorphism, and if you differentiate a Lie group antihomomorphism, you get precisely what you wrote.

Comment: Your proposed definition of a $\mathfrak{g}$-$\mathfrak{h}$-bimodule does not have the desired property that it makes $\mathfrak{g}$ into a $\mathfrak{g}$-$\mathfrak{g}$-bimodule. This is also explained in the question details (in the first item of the list).

Comment: But would this same argument not also go for bimodules over commutative rings? And those are definitely interesting.